# Another Undefined Index (this one's defined though)

Tags: php, mysql, variables, indexing

Alright, PHP is throwing this error (in the log) and it's quite detrimental to the application.

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: sessid in methods.php on line 7
```

Yes, I'm aware of what this error means, what I cannot figure out is why it's obviously defined and saying it's undefined. Here is the relevant code in methods.php

```
$sessid = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['sessid']);
```

Now before you go off and say that "NO IT'S UNDEFINED!!!", here is the POST request to the methods.php (and yes, I'm also aware that $_REQUEST "can't be trusted").

```
method=r&room=general&sessid=d0sma94yw4r4cdckv2ufhb&qid=1276957562382
```

As you can see, the sessid is obviously defined and is being sent off to the methods.php. I just thought I'd throw in the relevant query here too.

```
mysql_query('UPDATE active SET time=\''.$timestamp.'\' WHERE sessid=\''.$sessid.'\'');
```

Yes, time is also defined as:

```
$time = time();
```

So, what is the issue here?

Comment: Can you try `$_GET["sessid"]` ? Are you using any libraries or frameworks that might unset `$_REQUEST`? WHat does `var_dump($_REQUEST);` say?

Comment: `var_dump` is `array(1) { ["sessid"]=>  string(21) "d0sma94yw4r4cdckv2ufhb" }`

Comment: If that's the var_dump(), why did the `method`,`room` & `qid` keys disappear?

Comment: Alright, this is a bit weird, but I did another `var_dump` through the application, not just the URL based one this time, and here are the results (with an obvious undefinition of the `sessid` variable).`array(4) { ["method"]=>  string(1) "r" ["room"]=>  string(7) "general" ["sessid"]=>  string(0) "" ["qid"]=>  string(13) "1276959603731" }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barring typos etc, if you have a version >= 5.3.0, you might want to check what `request_order` (or `variables_order` if `request_order` is empty) ini-setting is set to. If in none of those two the 'P' is set, the $_POST array will not be in $_REQUEST (and not even set it the 'P' is not in `variables_order` afaik). See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order

If those 2 are allright, I'd say you have a logical error somewhere else, var_dump() the `$_POST`  and `$_REQUEST` superglobals to check.

Comment: I also have other variables being requested and processed, and they are processed without error. It's just `sessid`.

Comment: Do you have `register_globals` enables, and are you using (and possibly unsetting) a `$sessid` variable somewhere?

Comment: `register_globals` is off, and `$sessid` is validated but that happens before it gets to the page that sends data to `methods.php`.

Comment: Solved. I had a typo in the form that submits `sessid`, and setting the method to `$_POST` worked.