# Undefined index on parameter, cannot define

Tags: php, string, variables

Hello I receive the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: $db_field.

It's because I have not declared the parameter: `$db_field` - when this function is called:

```
if (checkInField($webmailUserName,$db_connection,$db_con_table,"userName") == false)
```

The fourth bit is a clear string, PHP is not like Java where your declare the variables int, long, string, etc.  So I used echo `$db_field` and sure enough the echo onscreen shows 'userName' so I think its recognised as a string?

I have tried `echo $row[$db_field];` (does not work)

I have tried `echo $row['db_field'];` (indicating a string using `'` does not work / if I understand right)

I have tried `echo $row['userName'];` (this string works)

I can however check with `isset()` which I do not understand how to do.  Other posts with my error description do not seem to match what I'm trying to achieve.

Please can someone explain to me why `echo $row[]` does not recognise `'$db_field'` as a string and what is needed to fix it.  Hopefully this will help other beginners too.

I'm using PHP5.3 and cannot check any server ini's as I'm using a domain and webserver company for my script.  ([Another Undefined Index (this one's defined though)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075819/another-undefined-index-this-ones-defined-though))

```
function checkInField($value,$db_connection,$db_con_table, $db_field)  
// Checks a value is not within a database field
{       
    $query = "SELECT $db_field FROM $db_con_table WHERE $db_field='$value'"; 
    $result = $db_connection->query($query) or die($mysqli->error());

    // GOING THROUGH THE DATA
    if($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            echo $row['$db_field']; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'NO RESULTS';  
    }
```

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Comment: Seems like you're not following the function's same sequence. Your conditional's first parameter is `$webmailUserName` yet the first variable in the function itself is `$value`

Comment: hi Fred the webmailUserName is the form field which is the value.  The userName is the SQL database column which is db_field,  may be better to call it db_column

Comment: John have removed the reference, I just wanted to demonstrate before the bad posts saying there are plenty of places to look online, that I've given this a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning (aka Notice) about `Undefined index: $db_field` should indicate that you're trying to perform an array-index (like `Map.get()` in Java) with the string `$db_field`. (When you typed in `'$db_field'`, you expected it to evaluate to be `userName`, but it isn't.)

This is because in PHP, single-quoted strings are different than double-quoted strings. ([PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php))

So, instead of this:

```
echo $row['$db_field']; // indexing with the literal string $db_field
```

... use:

```
echo $row[$db_field]; // if $db_field is numeric, acts like List.get(int); if $db_field is a string, acts like Map.get(Object)
```

or

```
echo $row["$db_field"]; // indexing with the string-representation of the variable named $db_field
```

---

About forward-declaring variables: One of your method parameters is named `$db_field`, so it's perfectly safe to refer to the variable of that name inside your method (but not outside it). I think you assumed the `Undefined...` had to do with the variable itself, but that is not the case.

Comment: Yes that's correct I thought it was the variable itself where the problem was, the double quotes solved it.  Thank you